# Changing the state of a React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parent-child, react-component

Maybe it's the way I am wording things, but I am not getting the answer I want on the following topic. So currently, my code looks like this (minus all the details):

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
  <Autocomplete options={someList} />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

So I have two questions.

- Is Autocomplete component here considered to be an extension of ClickAwayListener? Is ClickAwayListener considered a parent component?
- I want the handleClickAway function to change the *options* state within Autocomplete. How would I go about doing this?

I am pretty new to React, so I would appreciate any and all help. Thank you in advance.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like most likely you are using your click away component not in a way it was intended to be used. It looks like it should be used with [this technique](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
  {(isClickedAway) => (
    {/*or whatever api your Autocomplete has*/}
    <Autocomplete options={someList} isOpen={!isClickedAway} />
  )}
</ClickAwayListener>
```

As to your questions:

- ClickAwayListener is a parent of Autocomplete. There's no such thing as extension in react tree.
- in your `handleClickAway` you have to change `someList`. If it comes through the state, then with `setState`, if it comes from props - with a corresponding callback.